# What should an installation of Python 2.5 look like on Windows XP?

Tags: python, windows-xp

I installed Python a while ago from the official python-2.5.4.msi, but I can't remember what else I might have done. On my disk, I have C:\Program Files\Python 2.5.4 and I also have C:\Python25.  These directory contents look almost identical.  The Program Files folder contains about 39 MB, the Python25 folder contains about 25 MB.  Where did these come from?

In my start menu I have a Python 2.5 folder with a IDLE (Python GUI) shortcut and a few other things.

These two disk locations are really confusing me. I'm trying to install modules and it's getting messed up.  When I ran ez_setup.py to install easy_install, it went into the Python25 directory, but Python seems to be searching for modules in the Program Files location. Or some awful mess like that. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Orginally, python 2.5 installed itself in C:/ and not C:/Program Files, but in the latest .msi this might have changed. Nevertheless, the best way is to uninstall all python installations, delete both the folders C:\Program Files\Python 2.5.4 (unless you have data in them) and again install the python interpreter and other 3rd party python packages you use. It is not good to have 2 installations of the same versions of the python interpreter at different locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you might have installed python twice, each time using a different installation directory. You might want to consider uninstalling the two existing copies and installing a new copy.

Also...The following document should help you to understand how and where python installs and locates modules: [Installing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.4/inst/inst.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other application using Python?
It's also possible that applications install python for themself.
An example could be a game, which uses Python for the AI.
As far as i know, Panda3d installs its "own" Python...